# CoreImage patches problems in 10.6

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, core-image

In 10.6 with some systems CoreImage CIPerspectiveTransform (And other api's too) results in colored patches  in output image. (It seems like hardware related issue And it occurs only with images with resolution above 4000X2500)

Is there ay way to come out of this bug?
At-last is it possible to use NSAffineTransform  instead?
If yes how to use it.

Thanks,
Dhana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating your `CIContext`, have you tried disabling the hardware renderer? This fixed problems for me:

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort]
                                             options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer, nil]];
```

Comment: Great info! Probably makes sense to make disabling of hardware rendering dependent on the image size so you would still use it for smaller images,