# How to set Image Perspective

Tags: cocoa, image, macos

I am working in Mac OS X, 10.6

How can i set the image perspective of any image?

I do not want to use CoreImage.

Is it possible to do it via NSAffineTransforms.

Regards,
Dhana.

Comment: I can't think of a _single_ reason not to use CoreImage.

Comment: Apparently the OP is experiencing a problem with large images (greater than 4000 x 2500 px) when using CI. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553793/coreimage-patches-problems-in-10-6 This should be mentioned in the question though.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that does not use CoreImage, you'll need to implement the transformation yourself. It cannot be done as an affine transform. [This paper](http://torus.untergrund.net/misc/projective_image_warping.pdf) explains the process pretty good.

If you can't code it yourself, you could look at other third-party libraries that implement perspective transform. One such option would be [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). They offer perspective transform as a command line utility and they also have a C API that you could use to get the same functionality in your own program.

Comment: Thanks VP.
Is there any way to tackle patches issues with CoreImage in 10.6?

Comment: Have you tried disabling hardware rendering? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553793/coreimage-patches-problems-in-10-6/1554740#1554740

Answer (score 0):

You can't express a perspective transform with an affine transformation. However, in CoreImage you can use an ImageUnit (CoreImage's name for what you would normally call a "filter") to do a perspective transform on an image (and many other cool things).

See [CIPerspectiveTransform](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveTransform) and check out the [section about CoreImage Filters](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-TPXREF101) in the CoreImage developer's guide. That should get you going.

Basically what you do is...

```
perspectiveTransform = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPerspectiveTransform"];
[perspectiveTransform setDefaults];
[perspectiveTransform setValue: myCIImage forKey: @"inputImage"];
[perspectiveTransform setValue: myToLeft forKey: @"inputTopLeft"];
// ... also set inputTopRight, inputBottomLeft and inputBottomRight
// if you have the coordinates of the corner points you can create
// CIVector instances with 
// + (CIVector *)vectorWithX:(CGFloat)x Y:(CGFloat)y
// ...
result = [perspectiveTransform valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
```

Comment: Yes, Using CoreImage filters works fine.
But below mentioned defect arises.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553793/coreimage-patches-problems-in-10-6

So i want to avoid using this to get rid of the bug.

Comment: Sorry. I read that you wanted to use CoreImage not that you specifically didn't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle perspective on your image would be to apply a 3-D transformation, with perspective, using Core Animation.  You could place your image within a CALayer (as that layer's contents), or layer-back your NSImageView.  I describe how to create and apply a perspective CATransform3D to a layer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform/353611#353611), but the key is to set the m34 element of the CATransform3D to a negative fraction in order to create a perspective effect.  Mike Lee has a writeup on this [here](http://www.atomicwang.org/motherfucker/Index/B4E5D81C-A9A0-403C-B7A3-62FEB81DE777.html), along with some [sample code](http://boondoggle.atomicwang.org/lemurflip/).